# How to keep Elements to separate pages - for printing - without overflow to additional page

Tags: html, css, image, printing, html-table

I am trying to print some tables and an image on two separate pages.

However when I do this I always get additional page that spills over into a 3rd page when I am trying to print.

How do I get rid of the additional page space or overflow that appears on a 3rd page when printing?

I have added page break after and before in the past in various places to remedy this with no success.

The tables will move in size due to data that is shoved in them - but never more than a page. So the image on the secopnd page needs to allow for that as well as keeping to the second page. I am struggling with this. I've tried using absolute position to get it to stay fixed, but it still moves when the table moves, pushing into a third page at times.

Any suggestions help. Thanks

HTML:

```
<body>

<table class="tableWrapper" cellpadding="3">
    <tr class="no-counter">
        <td>
        <table class="table headingTable">
            <tr class="no-counter">
                <td>Total<br />Persons<br />Onboard</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="table headingTable">
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <th colspan="4">&nbsp;<#Tour_Resource type="lookup" value="resource_resource" display="resource_name"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td><#Tour_Date_In format="ddd d mmm yyyy"></td>
                    <td>Wind Direction</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Dept Time</td>
                    <td><#Tour_Date_In format="h:nn am/pm"></td>
                    <td>Wind Strength</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Ret Time</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Swell/Waves</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Dive Site</td>
                    <td>
                        <#Tour_TourTemp type="lookup" value="tourtemp_tourtemp" display="tourtemp_name">
                    </td>
                    <td>Tide</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="table headingTable">
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <th colspan="2">Dive Plan / Skipper</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Planned Total Dive Time</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;">min</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Time in (first dive)</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">:</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Time out (last dive)</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">:</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Master/Skipper</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>    
            <table class="table headingTable">
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <th colspan="2">Boat Crew</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td nowrap>G.P Crew 1</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td nowrap>G.P Crew 2</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td nowrap>G.P Crew 3</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td nowrap>G.P Crew 4</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>    
            <table class="table headingTable">
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <th colspan="4">Passenger Count</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td colspan="2">Before Departure</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Before Return</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Divers</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Divers</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Non Divers</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Non Divers</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Signed</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Signed</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>    
            <table class="table headingTable">
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <th colspan="2">Checks</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Air On & Checked</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>BCDs Connected?</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>BCDs Inflate?</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr class="no-counter">
                    <td>Signed</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />

<table class="table service-cart">
    <tr class="no-counter">
        <th>#</th>
        <th style="margin:0; padding: 0;">Buddy<br/>Group</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Booked</th>
        <th>Loc</th>
        <th>Last Dive</th>
        <th>Air Full</th>
        <th>Plan<br/>Depth</th>
        <th>Plan<br/>Bottom<br/>Time</th>
        <th>Safety<br/>Stop<br/>Time</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">Total<br/>Time</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px;">Gas<br/>Mix</th>
        <th>M.O.D.</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">In<br/>Time</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">Out<br/>Time</th>
        <th>Actual<br/>Depth</th>
        <th>Actual<br/>Run<br/>Time</th>
        <th>Stops<br/>Cmpld</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; text-align: left;">Sign for<br/>- Dive Parameters Done<br />- Returned Onboard</th>
    </tr>
    <#Reference filter="reference_status = 'A'" order="Guest_surname">
    <tr style="background-color: #ffffff;">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="text-left"><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">M</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">%</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">M</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #ffffff;">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="text-left"><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">M</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">%</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">M</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

</table>

<hr class="break">

<div class="second">
    <img src="/vessellog.png" class="dlog">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styletable.css">
  <style>

    table tbody tr:not(.no-counter) {
        counter-increment: rowNumber;
    }

    table tbody tr:not(.no-counter) td:nth-child(1)::before {
        content: counter(rowNumber);
        min-width: 1em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
    }

    .headingTable {
        height: 150px;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .tableWrapper {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .second {      
        transform: rotate(270deg);
        margin-left: 180px;
        margin-top: -60px;
        width: 720px;
        height: 1080px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .dlog {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    .break {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve my issue what I did was add: `<div style="page-break-before:always;"> </div>` after the last `<table>` on first page. This created the page break I needed to print on separate pages. As in:

```
</table> /* End of First Page */
<div style="page-break-before: always;"> </div> 

<div class="vlogimage"> /*Second Page*/
    <img class="logologext" alt='<#Business_name>' src= "<#servername>/<#Register_Directory>/<#Splash_Logo>?v=<#now format='yy-mm-dd-hh-nn'>">
    <p class="vlogtext"><#Business_name> Daily Vessel Log</p>
    <img src="/vessellog.png" class="dlog" >
</div>
```

I tried applying `page-break-before: always;` to the first `<div>` on my second page and this did not work how I was hoping.

Hope this helps someone out there!